# <ul> element not rendering properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have problem with rendering  in Firefox. My code is working fine in Chrome and IE. Menu elements with the submenus are going few pixels down when rendering in Firefox.

Here is the example images:

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Give us more than pictures to work with? how about a fiddle of your menu?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iCromwell/7gEya/ - just enlarge result screen little bit to see clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. Removing dipslay: inline-block; from #cssmenu span element did it. Removing padding from #cssmenu > ul > li > a and giving margin to #cssmenu also works fine also.

Comment: I also noticed that i have to use inline-block. Removing padding from #cssmenu > ul > li > a and giving margin to #cssmenu also works fine with inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your `inline block`.

[image]

but this does shift everything to the left, not sure if thats what you want?

Comment: Thank you for you answer but i already resolved it. Removing inline-block is solving the rendering problem of Firefox but menu must be stretched to the div, so it wasn't working form. But removing padding from #cssmenu > ul > li > a and giving margin to #cssmenu did the trick.